# Multiple QR code - 1 Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, url

I have this complex request:
in my Data Extension every Subscriber has a personalised URL (**that shows a specific qr code**), I have to create only 1 email that shows this "dynamic" QR.

Example Data Extension:

1. John -> URL = qrn1.com
2. Erik -> URL = qrn2.com
3. Jack -> URL = qrn3.com

Example Email 1:
*"Dear John,
scan the following code to register to the event:
------image of the qr with URL **qrn1.com**-------
See you soon"*

Example Email 2:
*"Dear Jack,
scan the following code to register to the event:
------image of the qr with URL **qrn3.com**-------
See you soon"*

Which function can I use?

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Marketing Cloud doesn't have a native function to create QR code but you can use AMPscript [BarcodeURL](https://ampscript.guide/barcodeurl/) function to create a DataMatrix barcode. It looks similar like a QR code.

E.g.

```
%%[
    var @imgURL
    set @url = "http://example.com/"
    set @imgURL = BarCodeURL(@url, "DataMatrix", "250", "250")
]%%
<img src="%%=v(@imgURL)=%%" alt="QR code">
```

Output:
[image]

Otherwise, you have to rely on a third party service (may involve to an additional cost) where it supports to create and manage the QR code.

For this example bellow, I used [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes) to create the QR code.

```
%%[
    var @imgURL
    set @url = "http://example.com/"
    set @QRAPIURL= "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&choe=UTF-8"
    set @QRsize = Concat("&chs=", "250x250")
    set @content = Concat("&chl=" ,  @url)
    set @imgURL = Concat(@QRAPIURL, @QRsize, @content)
]%%
<img src="%%=v(@imgURL)=%%" alt="QR code">
```

Output: [image]